# capybara waiting for ajax without using sleep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara, ngtable

I'm using Capybara 2.x for some integration tests for a large Rails/AngularJS app and I've come across a test in which I need to put a sleep to get it working.

My test:

```
describe "#delete", js: true do
  it "deletes a costing" do
    costing = Costing.make!

    visit "/api#/costings"
    page.should have_content("General")

    click_link "Delete"     # Automatically skips the confirm box when in capybara

    sleep 0.4
    page.should_not have_content("General")
  end
end
```

The code it tests is using ng-table which takes a split second to update, without that sleep it will fail. Capybara used to have a wait_until method for this but it's been taken out. I found this website: http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara but cannot get any of the recommended alternatives working for this problem.

Here is the code I'm testing.

```
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Delete
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.destroy = (id) ->
    Costing.delete (id: id), (response) -> # Success
      $scope.tableParams.reload()
      flash("notice", "Costing deleted", 2000)
```

This updates the ng-table (tableParams variable) which is this code

```
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    sorting: {name: 'asc'}
  },{
    total: 0,

    getData: ($defer, params) ->
      Costing.query {}, (data) ->
        # Once successfully returned from the server with my data process it.
        params.total(data.length)

        # Filter
        filteredData = (if params.filter then $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) else data)

        # Sort
        orderedData = (if params.sorting then $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) else data)

        # Paginate
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try bumping the `Capybara.default_wait_time` up to 3 seconds or 4.

If that fails, try changing the spec to look for the flash notice message before it checks to see if the item has been removed from the page. (Assuming the flash message gets rendered in the HTML body)

```
describe "#delete", js: true do
  it "deletes a costing" do
    costing = Costing.make!

    visit "/api#/costings"
    page.should have_content("General")

    click_link "Delete"

    page.should have_content("Costing deleted")
    page.should_not have_content("General")
  end
end
```

**Edit** - removed explanation because it was incorrect.

Comment: It still breaks on the should_not test, it passes the flash message test. I also tried bumping up the default wait time to 5 seconds, but it didn't help. I still have to put that sleep in.

Comment: it is worth noting that the `have_` capybara methods in general will trigger waiting behavior, based on the default wait time